# Entity Framework / LINQ - Date From / Date To Comparison

Tags: entity-framework, linq, date, entity

I have an extremely simple situation yet I can't find the answer to it anywhere on the Net.

I wish to implement a **simple search form** which allows users to **query for database records which has a timestamp between a From Date and a To Date** chosen by the user. The user can **also filter the results by a substring of a text field** called Sample Number.

The query works if I only do a substring search and drop the capability of comparing dates from the where clause. **As soon as I compare dates in the where clause the query returns no results.**

Here are the outcomes from different tests done:

This query searches for a **date that falls in a range** and produces no result at all (when there should be some by right), so this does not work:

```
public List<devicereading> getDeviceReadings(String entityConnStr, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String sampleNo)
{
    labinstrumentconnection lc = new labinstrumentconnection(entityConnStr);
    List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => d.datetime >= fromDate && d.datetime <= toDate && d.samplenumber.Contains(sampleNo)).ToList();
    return ll;
}
```

This one searches on a single date comparison only ie. for **a date after a given date** only but it also produces no result, so this does not work:

```
public List<devicereading> getDeviceReadings(String entityConnStr, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String sampleNo)
{
    labinstrumentconnection lc = new labinstrumentconnection(entityConnStr);
    List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => d.datetime >= fromDate).ToList(); 
    return ll;
}
```

This one does only a substring search and does **no date comparison**. This one works!

```
public List<devicereading> getDeviceReadings(String entityConnStr, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String sampleNo)
{
    labinstrumentconnection lc = new labinstrumentconnection(entityConnStr);
    List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => d.samplenumber.Contains(sampleNo)).ToList();
    return ll;
}
```

I can't see what's wrong anymore. Hope there's someone out there who can see where the problem is.

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you run the last (**no date comparison**) query, can you open the result list and see if it contains items with dates that fall into the range? Also are you storing dates only or you have also a time portion?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the query. You may need to check if you actually have data with date falls in that range. Try for a wider date range.

Comment: What do you see if you monitor the SQL queries? Do these queries return results when run in SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DbFunction.TruncateTime` from `System.Data.Entity` namespace to compare dates without worry about time.

```
public List<devicereading> getDeviceReadings(String entityConnStr, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String sampleNo)
{
    labinstrumentconnection lc = new labinstrumentconnection(entityConnStr);
    var fromDateWithoutTime = fromDate.Date
    List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => DbFunction.TruncateTime(d.datetime) >= fromDateWithoutTime).ToList(); 
    return ll;
}

public List<devicereading> getDeviceReadings(String entityConnStr, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String sampleNo)
{
    labinstrumentconnection lc = new labinstrumentconnection(entityConnStr);
    var toDateWithoutTime = toDate.Date
    var fromDateWithoutTime = fromDate.Date
    List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => DbFunction.TruncateTime(d.datetime) >= fromDateWithoutTime && DbFunction.TruncateTime(d.datetime) <= toDateWithoutTime && d.samplenumber.Contains(sampleNo)).ToList();
    return ll;
}
```

Comment: Time component doesn't matter if you look in a range of dates.

Comment: Thank you very much AlbertoMonteiro. Your solution works beautifully. Appreciate the time you put into rewriting the codes.

Just a note for those stuck in the namespace confusion of EF6 (like me), here's the code for EF6

            var fromDateWithoutTime = fromDate.Date;
            var toDateWithoutTime = toDate.Date;
      
            List<devicereading> ll = lc.devicereadings.Where(d => System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.datetime) >= fromDate && System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.datetime) <= toDate && d.samplenumber.Contains(sampleNo)).ToList();

Comment: So now a date/time of, for example, 2015-12-12 23:59 is within the range 2015-12-01 00:00 - 2015-12-12 00:00. That doesn't make sense to me. To me your problem is about choosing the right ranges ( - 2015-12-13 00:00), not about ignoring time components.

Comment: @GertArnold Really? This make no sense.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Give me arguments.

Comment: @GertArnold I created a gist to explain it for you https://gist.github.com/AlbertoMonteiro/df93bdf6296c25b07ce1

Comment: Thanks, that's something I can respond to. In my opinion in such cases, the *visible* range should be translated to a hidden/used range + 1 day (using `<`, not <=`). Transforming database columns before searching on them is not sensible. (More exactly: not sargable).

Comment: @GertArnold I respect your opinion, but I dont like to work in this way.